# Responsive CSS Not Working

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Here is my css, as a test:

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;outline:0;border:0;}

body{background:#686465;font-family:Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;font-size:100%;}
@media screen and (max-device-width:320px){
    body{background:red !important;}
}

@media screen and (max-device-width:800px){
    body{background:organge !important;}
}
```

I have 2 android devices running using the SDK to test this. One is 3.2 inch HVGA Slider 320x480, and the first rule picks up on this device and sets the body background to red. The second device is Nexus 7 800x1280, but this one ignores both of the media rules; however if i delete the first media rule then it picks it up. Why??

Comment: Presumably "orange" is correctly spelled on your live rules? As an invalid value this would be ignored by the layout engine. Rohit has corrected the spelling. I do not believe the order has any significance except where multiple media query rules match and have duplicate properties for the same selector, in which case the value from the last media query would be applied.

Comment: It is probably also worth mentioning that the Developer tools for your browser of choice are invaluable in working out these kinds of "why isn't this working" questions, as well as "playing around" with values without having to repeatedly save your CSS and refresh the site. If you use Google Chrome as your primary browser then there is an excellent free course on using the dev tools at http://www.codeschool.com/courses/discover-devtools. Whichever browser you use, time learning the developer tools will be time well spent.

Answer (score 8):

Have you put this link in your html file:-

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0;">
```

you can use-

```
@media only screen and (max-width:800px){ }
```

instead of-

```
@media screen and (max-device-width:800px){ }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Replace into this**

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;outline:0;border:0;}

body{background:#686465;font-family:Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;font-size:100%;}
@media screen and (max-device-width:320px){
    body{background:red !important;}
}

@media screen and (max-device-width:800px){
    body{background:organge !important;}
}
```

**this**

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;outline:0;border:0;}

body{background:#fcfcfc;font-family:Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;font-size:100%;}


@media screen and (max-device-width:800px){
    body{background:orange;}
}

@media screen and (max-device-width:320px){
    body{background:red ;}
}
```

More about **[media query-1](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)**

**[Media query-2](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)**

Comment: well that worked. all you did different was put the larger one first?